# Issue with an exam extra credit question

Tags: linear-algebra

forgive me if this question may come off as incoherent ( I've just gotten home from the bar with friends and am not in the most clear state of thought). My question arises from an extra credit question I got wrong on my first Linear Algebra exam of this semester. The question was of 3-4 parts or so on a certain mxn coefficient matrix ( I do not remember the exact entries forgive me). But, when  reduced to REF and examined the coefficient matrix had only 2 pivot positions and exactly 2 free variables (this I am sure of). The extra credit was posed as such:

" Extra Credit : Are the columns of the following matrix linearly independent? "

I answered verbatim as:

" The columns of the matrix are linearly dependent for the matrix has free variables, and thus the nontrivial solution. "

The answer was marked incorrect and I'm honestly confused. It was to my understanding that the definition of linear independence was a set of vectors in which the solutions to the homogeneous matrix equation was only the trivial solution. And, that the presence of free variables in your given matrix introduced non-trivial solutions into the nul space of your matrix. I really don't know if I'm just flat out wrong in my answer or he was upset in the terse way I worded the answer ( under exam conditions i'm in a rush ). So to sum up I'd just want to know if my reasoning is flawed or not. And if so, if anyone can provide any explanation/intuition for determining whether or not a dependence relation exist among the columns of a matrix.

Comment: Consider talking to the person responsible for grading the exam. We really can't say much about the intentions, especially since you can't remember the exact matrix and question statements.

Comment: Yes, I figured this may be the proper course of action. I just wanted to try and ask the forum. Thank-you for your time.

Comment: Your idea is correct though. If a matrix has free columns in an REF, its columns are linearly dependent.

Comment: Thank-you! I apologize once again for not providing the exact entries of the coefficient matrix. But, it was just a validation ( and or correction) of my reasoning I was seeking.